# How do I replace null with 0 out of pivot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to replace NULL with 0 in pivot table so i can do some calculation but look like it's not working with isnull.
Do you have any suggestion? Should I manually list all the column names and do isnull manual for each of them instead of select *. from a temporary table? I'm using SQL. Thanks

```
select * from #b                 
               pivot ISNULL((max (qtysold),0) )
               for letterrank in ([A1],[A2],[A3],[A4],[A5],[A6],[A7],[A8],[A9],[A10],[A11],[A12],[A13])) AS TotalSold
```

Comment: not sure if it will help but you could try coalesce instead of isNull.  But I'm guessing this is T-SQL so isNull should work..

Comment: Hi xQbert, I tried  isnull but Null is still there. I guess there's a code for this, not just regular change with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
select ISNULL([A1], 0) AS [A1]
      ,ISNULL([A2], 0) AS [A2]
      ,ISNULL([A3], 0) AS [A3]
      ,ISNULL([A4], 0) AS [A4]
      ,........ and so on....
from #b                 
   pivot (max (qtysold) 
           for letterrank 
           in ([A1],[A2],[A3],[A4],[A5],[A6],[A7],[A8],[A9],[A10],[A11],[A12],[A13])) AS TotalSold
```